# Make file echo displaying "$PATH" string

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to force make file to display next string:

```
"Please execute next commands:
setenv PATH /usr/local/greenhills/mips5/linux86:$PATH"
```

The problem is with `"$PATH"`. Command

```
@echo "setenv PATH /usr/local/greenhills/mips5/linux86:$PATH"
```

cause a result

```
"setenv PATH /usr/local/greenhills/mips5/linux86:ATH"
```

any combinations of escape characters, quotes, `"$(shell echo "` didn't get required results...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In the [manual for GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Value-Function), they talk about this specific example when describing the `value` function:

> The value function provides a way for you to use the value of a
>   variable without having it expanded. Please note that this does not
>   undo expansions which have already occurred; for example if you create
>   a simply expanded variable its value is expanded during the
>   definition; in that case the value function will return the same
>   result as using the variable directly.
>
> The syntax of the value function is:
>
> ```
>  $(value variable)
> ```
>
> Note that variable is the name of a variable; not a reference to that variable. Therefore you would not normally use
>   a ‘$’ or parentheses when writing it. (You can, however, use a
>   variable reference in the name if you want the name not to be a
>   constant.)
>
> The result of this function is a string containing the value of
>   variable, without any expansion occurring. For example, in this
>   makefile:
>
> ```
>  FOO = $PATH
>
>  all:
>          @echo $(FOO)
>          @echo $(value FOO)
> ```
>
> The first output line would be ATH, since the “$P” would be expanded as a make variable, while the second
>   output line would be the current value of your $PATH environment
>   variable, since the value function avoided the expansion.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that variable declaration is done outside of target. Can they be defined inside a target?

Answer (score 30):

The `make` uses the `$` for its own [variable expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference). E.g. single character variable `$A` or variable with a long name - `${VAR}` and `$(VAR)`.

To put the `$` into a command, use the `$$`, for example:

```
all:
  @echo "Please execute next commands:"
  @echo 'setenv PATH /usr/local/greenhills/mips5/linux86:$$PATH'
```

Also note that to `make` the `""` and `''` (double and single quoting) do not play any role and they are passed verbatim to the shell. (Remove the `@` sign to see what `make` sends to shell.) To prevent the shell from expanding `$PATH`, second line uses the `''`.

Comment: Thank you, you gave me the direction! @echo "setenv PATH /usr/local/greenhills/mips5/linux86:$$PATH"
case to whole $PATH to be printed, but @echo 'setenv PATH /usr/local/greenhills/mips5/linux86:$$PATH' do the job!

Comment: Because, as I have noted the `""` and `''` are passed to the shell. Inside the `""` shell would expand the `$PATH`, but not inside the `''`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder it's been soooo long since I used make

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I always forget the bit myself and at first do the same mistake too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Tricky

Makefile snippet - on how to print and how to use

```
CURRENTDIR =  $(shell pwd)
PARENTDIR = $(shell dirname $(CURRENTDIR))
#HOME =  $${HOME} No need of this
#PATH = $${PATH} or this

test:
    $(info  HOME is  $(value HOME) PATH is $(value PATH))
    $(info  HOME is  $(HOME) PATH is $(PATH))
    -$(shell unzip xx.zip -d $(HOME)/.local)
    $(export PATH := $(PATH):$(HOME)/.local/bin)
```

Output

`make test`

```
HOME is  /home/alex PATH is /home/alex/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/cuda/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
HOME is  /home/alex PATH is /home/alex/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/cuda/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```