# How to determine environment variables set by netbeans on the command line

Tags: c, windows, netbeans, mingw

I have a C project that I am building on a Windows 10 host in netbeans using MinGW for the compilers. I can clean and build the project fine.

I tried cleaning the project from the command line using exactly the same command that netbeans shows in its Output tab:

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug clean
```

However, when I run this, the 'rm' command is not recognised (whereas in netbeans it is). I assume this is something to do with an environment variable setting that netbeans uses (which should point to C:\MingGW\msys\1.0\bin ), but I can't find it anywhere in the netbeans project configuration files.

In the netbeans Makefile-Debug it uses the Makefile environment variable ${RM} but on printing this to screen it references 'rm -f'.

Comment: Try modifying your Makefile according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12111527/2429333)

Comment: If I do 
    $(value RM)
I see:
    rm -f -r build/Debug

. So still no idea of path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try submitting `where rm` from the command line.

If it fails (and presumably it will with the error *Could not find files for the given pattern(s))*, then you need to add `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` to your `PATH`, and then try `make` again in a new **Command Prompt** window. If you still have problems after doing that:

- Verify that `where rm` is now locating `rm` in  `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`.
- Update your question with the actual error reported on the command line when you call `make`, and the content of your **PATH** variable.

Comment: It turned out I needed to add C:\MinGW\bin and C:\cygwin\bin as well as C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin for everything to work. Thanks for the pointer.